# OneDrive for business /Sharepoint: Unable to use GetFileByGuestUrl to validate/invalidate a guest url

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, onedrive-for-business

I'm trying to use the method [`GetFileByGuestUrl`](http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.in/2016_01_01_archive.html) to validate the guest URL that I have for my document. The issue is that I am unable to find an attribute in the response for this API call that would indicate that the link is not valid anymore.

I am using expired guest URLs and this method is still returning the meta data for the file without any information about the expiration of the link.

Comment: Maybe try GetFileByGuestUrlEnsureAccess and see if that gives any different response? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getfilebyguesturlensureaccess.aspx

Comment: Tried that, same result. Plus it doesn't allow me to use > ensureAccess > flag. I passed true/false, 0/1 doesn't work. It works without that flag, but the result is the same as >GetFileByGuestUrl > It doesn't mention whether the link has expired or is still valid.

Comment: Darn, sorry it looked to be promising.